# Drupal 7 + smoothdivscroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

Im having a problem with integrating the script smoothdivscroller into a page content, and since my knowledge of html , css and js is extremely weak, i cant find the problem -- here's my theme .info file http://www.fpaste.org/wcNv/ and here's the content       http://www.fpaste.org/cDDm/
so instead of getting it working right, all i get is the images stacked next to each other
what's wrong? I'm just following the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing this in your local machine make the jquery link like as given below with http:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Mate, you are a legend, I've wasted 1.5 days trying everything. Thanks!! :)